# Android Studio Gradle - Unable to link classes, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

So my builds are working fine on Android 5.0, but on 4.0 it throws a NoClassDefFoundError for one of my own classes.

Before and after that exception it is also displaying link errors for my own classes, as well as pretty much all of my libraries.

I have proguard disabled using: `minifyEnabled false` and I do have `multidex` enabled

This definitely used to run on 4.0, but something in the last few days has caused it to stop.

I went through my entire revision history on git, and there have been no changes to any of the iml, of gradle files.

This appears to be a proguard issue, but it's disabled so I'm pretty confused

Comment: Post the contents of your build.gradle file

Comment: Have you updated to Android Studio 1.0? Perhaps that's the change that caused this issue.

Comment: Pay attention if you are using android.support.v# imports and your methods call the usual libraries.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Did you find a solution?